# Why isn't PHP responding to my $_GET variables?

Tags: php, get

I have the following code in index.php (simplified):

```
<?php
  print_r($_GET);
  if ($_GET['f'] == "activate") {
    //do stuff
  }

  if ($_GET['f'] == "disable") {
    //do stuff
  }
?>
```

and further down the page, some HTML:

```
<tr>
<td style='font-size: 0.9em;'>email@address.ac.uk</td>
<td style='font-size: 0.75em;'><span style="color: #00AF28;">Active</span></td><td style='font-size: 0.75em;'><a href="?f=disable&id=email@address.ac.uk">Disable</a></td>
</tr>
```

The two hyperlinks will point the browser to the URL `index.php?f=disable&id=email@address.ac.uk` and `index.php?f=disable&id=email@address.ac.uk`, respectively.

Upon clicking the hyperlink (and directing the browser to `index.php?f=disable&id=email@address.ac.uk`), the result of `print_r($_GET)` is:

```
Array ( [f] => disable [id] => email@address.ac.uk )
```

However, the 'if' statement:

```
if ($_GET['f'] == "disable") {
  //do stuff
}
```

Does not execute until I refresh the page, or press the enter key on the address bar.

I'm using Chrome 16 on OSX for this, with PHP5.

Many thanks

Comment: Can you show a live example of this? This sounds very odd.

Comment: Sure that the if statement is not executed? Have you tried it with an simple echo or with the print_r from above?

Comment: Question: is it safe to send a "disable" or "activate" command via $_GET parameter?

Comment: I might have seen this one - please try <a href="index.php?f=...> and retry

Comment: what do you want to do in the code block, it is working fine check your browser

Comment: This should work. No reason for it not to work. You should change your last `if` to `elseif` as not both of them can happen at once

Comment: check your browser cache settings and as Damien pointed out - activate / disable using get requests sounds a little bit unsafe - better use post anyway

Comment: Thanks all for the replies - I am beginning to wonder if this IS a caching issue related to Chrome (sounds crazy though) - this works 'as expected' in Firefox (I have also changed HREFs to "index.php?f=")  --- 

Regarding using the $_GET request - this isn't the ideal solution, however will be used for a very specific use-case where it won't be a security risk

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable the cache. You can do this by sending some http headers to the browser. Here are an example from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
?>
```